# What is the correct SRID?

Tags: leaflet, postgis

I tried to create a map using leaflet.js using the following code:

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                }).addTo(map);
```

What is the correct SRID for that map? I tried 4326 SRID. Unfortunately when the geometry viewer from PostGIS and the map from leaflet.js render a point, the point shows different location. Thank you.

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-crs

Comment: See also https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310091/what-does-the-default-crs-being-epsg3857-in-leaflet-mean/310124#310124

Comment: OSM and default leaflet projection are both 3857. Look at your point data projection.